# Tank Rig Driver Help

Tags: drivers

[image]

creating a very simple tank rig with a driver controlling the movements of the tracks. now I got the tracks to move forward but when rotating the control on the Z axis, the tracks don't don't move. Have linked a gif and image of the driver expressions. Any advice much helpful.

[Tank Rig GIF](https://imgur.com/gallery/7TLWC9a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "Local Space" to "World Space". Local Space does not work with objects that are parented.

Comment: Thanks for that, worked like a charm ^^

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm ^^